# REGEX: How to get include multiple newlines in a positive lookbehind?

Tags: regex

I have a text with multiple lines between `Chapter 1` and `Introduction`, how can I include in my current regex line `(?<=Chapter 1[\r\n]Introduction)(.*?)(?=Chapter 2)` to include multiple newlines like `(\n*)`. I've tried to put `(\n*)` or `[\n]*`, but that doesn't work.

Full text:

```
Chapter 1


Introduction

**Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text**

Chapter 2
Introduction

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
```

I'm trying to get the the text in `**`

Comment: First of all: why do you need lookahead? What exactly do you want with your regex?

Comment: You don't need lookbehind, try [`^Chapter 1[\r\n]+Introduction\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*(?=Chapter 2)`](https://regex101.com/r/nRvTlN/2/), get the required value from capture group 1

Comment: @ZorgoZ To get the text in between `Chapter 1 Introduction` and `Chapter 2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^Chapter.*?^Introduction\s+(.+?)(?=^Chapter|$)` with both **global**, **multiline** and **singleline** options are. The first group(s) will match all text between the *Introduction* and the next *Chapter* (or the end of the text).

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/znNHTv/1

**Update:**

This is even better as the previous one does not match multiline content text.

`(?<=^|\n)Chapter.+?Introduction\s+(.+?)(?=Chapter|$)`

with **global** and **singleline** options.
You have both lookbehind and lookahead to find chapter limits.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/znNHTv/2/
With a minimal imrovement you can extract chapter number and introduction text too.